# Make a list from dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, aggregate

From a data frame df (a and b are column names)

```
a b
xx Apple
yy Orange
zz Apple
dd Mango
pp Mango
```

I would like the output as

```
Apple xx,zz
Orange yy
Mango dd,pp
```

I tried `aggregate` and `group_by` but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Base R:

A single `aggregate` would be enough for this operation. Here you would apply `FUN` to column `a` with a grouping on column `b` (`a ~ b`). The function to use is `paste` with argument `collapse` so that the multiple strings would be collapsed into a single one.

```
aggregate(a ~ b, df, FUN = paste, collapse = ",")

       b     a
1  Apple xx,zz
2  Mango dd,pp
3 Orange    yy
```

---

#### Dplyr

Since you mentioned `group_by`, the correct syntax to do so in `dplyr` is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(b) %>% summarize(a = paste(a, collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  b      a    
  <chr>  <chr>
1 Apple  xx,zz
2 Mango  dd,pp
3 Orange yy
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `toString`, and `summarise` with `.by = b`(must have dplyr 1.1.0 for that)

```
df %>%
    summarise(a = toString(a), .by = b)
```